# android xml to file

Tags: xml, android, dom

The javax.xml.transform package is not included in the Android SDK, so how to write a dom doc to a file?

Answer (score 1):

- [org.w3c.dom](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html)
- [org.xml.sax](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html)
- [android.sax](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/sax/package-summary.html)
- [org.xmlpull.v1](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html)

If you can't decide which to use, note that SAX is the fastest way to work with XML, DOM being the slowest.